# Change different HTML buttons with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

```
    jQuery('#button1').removeClass('before');
    jQuery('#button1').addClass('after');
```

is the code used to change a single button in Jquery. I want to know how to change a button based on what button is pressed, when I have buttons named button1, button2, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(input[name^="button"]).removeClass('before')
$(input[name^="button"]).addClass('after')
```

This will select all input elements with name starting with `button` as specified in your example. Check [selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure all the buttons are of the same class, say `btnClass`. Then:

```
jQuery('.btnClass').click(function() {
  jQuery(this).removeClass('before').addClass('after');
});
```

Comment: Oops. I realized I asked the completely wrong question. I edited it to better say what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Note, that rather than manually "removing / adding" a class you could use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).
That aside, there are many ways to select multiple dom elements. Take a look at the available jQuery [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

For example you could use a class selector:

```
$('.before').toggleClass('after')
​
```

If you have a set of buttons that don't match a class selector but you know the id's you could do something like:

```
$('#number1, #number2').toggleClass('after')
```

**EDIT:**

Based upon your edit you could bind to a click event of the elements you want:

```
$('.before').on('click', function(e){
   $(this).toggleClass('after')
});
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/LqsqB/1/​

**EDIT 2:**

If you wanted to bind to a click event you would do so on [dom ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      $(function() {
            $('.before').on('click', function(e){
              $(this).toggleClass('after')
           });
      });

</script>
```

Comment: Looks good, but I need some more help (this is the extent of my experience with JQuery). Where do I put it? The code I currently have is here: http://pastebin.com/NcvNnpUy

Comment: @A.J. added another edit, you wouldn't bind a click event in the success callback of an ajax, but rather on ready.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `<button>` tags to create button then

```
$("button").click(function () {
   $(this).toggleClass('after')
});
```

If you use `<input type='button' />` then

```
 $("input[type='button']").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('after')
 });
```

See : http://jsfiddle.net/CWSY9/